# reusable form in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm writing CRUD app on MeteorJS. I have html form with a lot of different inputs. In update case I can't set default values for html inputs from mongodb. How can I use the same html form in create and update cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a form in a template with `{{>template}}` and use another one so that you could seperate the events binding (if you're doing it with meteor, otherwise you could just use `{{>form}}` if you're using JQuery

**Client Html**

```
<template name="form">
    <form>
        <input type="text" value="{{values.fieldname1}}"/>
    </form>
</template>

<template name="crud">
   <h1>Update</h1>
   {{>update}}
   <hr/>
   <h1>New</h1>
   {{>create}}
</template>

<template name="update">
 {{>form}}
</template>

<template name="create">
 {{>form}}
</template>
```

**Client Js**

```
Template.update.values = function() {
    return MyCollection.findOne()
}

Template.update.events({
    'submit':function(event,context) {
        //update your stuff (your data would be in context.data)
        event.preventDefault()
    }
});

Template.create.events({
    'submit':function(event,context) {
        //create your new item
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```